# How can StreamTokenizer work with end of line being both CR and LF or a combination?

Tags: java, eol

I'm trying to use StreamTokenizer to read in data from files. It currently works when the file is using the LF (\n) return. It does not work for CRLF (\n\r) or just CR (\r). Is there a way it can work for all three?

There is also no guarantee what format the file will be in, hence it needs to work for all 3.

Currently I can only find this, making it work for one of the three:

```java
public final static int TT_EOL = '\n';
```

Comment: Why are you using a `StreamTokenizer`? A `Scanner` would work, wouldn't it?

Comment: That's what the current code base I'm working on is using and I found this bug.

Comment: Well, you should switch to `Scanner`. `StreamTokenizer` doesn't allow you to change what kind of line endings to use. It's a really old API, been there since JDK 1!

Answer (score 1):

StreamTokenizer supports the various EOLs just fine. From the docs of the `eolIsSignificant` method:

> Determines whether or not ends of line are treated as tokens. If the flag argument is true, this tokenizer treats end of lines as tokens; the nextToken method returns TT_EOL and also sets the ttype field to this value when an end of line is read.
>
> A line is a sequence of characters ending with either a carriage-return character ('\r') or a newline character ('\n'). In addition, a carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character is treated as a single end-of-line token.
>
> If the flag is false, end-of-line characters are treated as white space and serve only to separate tokens.

In other words, if the flag is true (you didn't mention this), then these docs say that'll work fine. If the flag is false, it also works fine: Both `\r` and `\n` count as whitespace, and if eolIsSignificant is off, then these characters are no more special than the space.

Whatever your problem is, it has nothing to do with StreamTokenizer's ability to parse the various newline forms.

Note that the fact that `TT_EOL` is equal to `\n` is **total coincidence**. The various `TT_` constants just indicate what kind of token was read in; ordinarily you'd think it'd be defined as:

```
public static final int TT_WORD = 1;
public static final int TT_NUMBER = 2;
public static final int TT_EOL = 3;
public static final int TT_EOF = 4;
```

but they decided to get cutesy and define them as:

```
public static final int TT_WORD = -3;
public static final int TT_NUMBER = -2;
public static final int TT_EOL = 10;
public static final int TT_EOF = -1;
```

Who knows why. Note that `10` and `'\n'` are the exact same number: They are both the number 10. `'\n'` is just a weird way of writing that.

Possibly your code is taking `ttype` and then, I dunno, writing it out as a byte someplace, and a text editor that opens that file as a plain text file would interpret `10` as a unix-style line ending.

NB: The lone `\r` as line ending doesn't occur. The last major OS that did this is Mac OS (as in, before Mac OS X). The version that ceased to exist around **1997** - over 20 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using the flag as true.

Comment: After debugging, I've found that when the data text file ends in CRLF (\r\n). The tokenizer's ttype is 13, meaning it is CR (\r). So it is not counting the CRLF as one token. Any thoughts?  
This is the code I used to test it:  
```java
int tokenValue = m_Tokenizer.nextToken();

        System.out.println(tokenValue == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL);
        System.out.println(m_Tokenizer.ttype);
```

Comment: @ConorEgan no, you don't understand. ttype cannot be 13. It can only be 10, and that just means 'end of line', not 'the end of line took this form'. Read the API docs, you seem to completely misunderstand how it works.

Comment: I have read the API docs... Why does it output 13 when I print it then?

Comment: I am not. From debugging, I found the code that changes the ttype value from -3 to 13 is ```m_Tokenizer.nextToken()```